# DisplayForModel is not working mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My controller:

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View("normal", PostalAddressRepo.All() as IEnumerable<PostalAddress>);
    }
```

normal.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<object>
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

it is not displaying records, instead just displaying the below:

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ContactMechanism_4E4BC83827D1FE8C7CD34454310EF12DB90E894128F3024AEB8C7E9BF8843D2ASystem.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ContactMechanism_4E4BC83827D1FE8C7CD34454310EF12DB90E894128F3024AEB8C7E9BF8843D2A
```

If I use the below, it is working fine:

```
@model IEnumerable<object>
@foreach (object obj in Model)
{
@Html.DisplayFor(m => obj)
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong with displayformodel().

can somebody advise?

Answer (score 0):

Try eagerly loading the model before passing it to the view:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    var model = PostalAddressRepo.All() as IEnumerable<PostalAddress>;
    return View("normal", model.ToList());
}
```

Also make your view strongly typed to the same type as your model:

```
@model IEnumerable<PostalAddress>
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

Comment: I dont knw what is wrong. None of these solutions are working!!

Comment: The problem is with the default display template (object.cshtml). it has the condition if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1, but in my case the TemplateDepth is 2 and so the else part was not at all rendered. Not sure why default template checks depth. I may have diff model with diff depths and how can I handle it without overriding the object.cshtml????

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what you are trying to achieve and your specific scenario. Also showing your `object.cshtml` (since you are using a custom one) might have helped.

Comment: yes using the custom one helped. but cannt I achieve this without using custom one ??

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve in order to be able to tell you how to achieve it. Maybe you should start by describing your scenario and goals.

Answer (score 0):

That should be because the DisplayForModel() tries to retrive the best property type for each in your PostalAddress object.

So, because it doesn't find a best one, I guess it returns a string for the object, showing

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ContactMechanism_4E4BC83827D1FE8C7CD34454310EF12DB90E894128F3024AEB8C7E9BF8843D2ASystem.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ContactMechanism_4E4BC83827D1FE8C7CD34454310EF12DB90E894128F3024AEB8C7E9BF8843D2A
```

If you can, strongly type the view to the return model:

```
@model IEnumerable<PostalAddress>
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```